# Cannot instantiate the type in Generics

Tags: java, generics

I am using Apache common dbutils for handling my database related operations, for my front end I am using Dojo for which I want ArrayList for different POJO classes instead of simple ResultSet. Below is my current method and I have several methods like this, I want to implement Gnerics so that I can remove this repetition from the code. I tried to implement Generics but it is failing at `new BeanListHandler<?>(?.class);` point and I am getting

```
Cannot instantiate the type BeanListHandler<?>
```

Kindly help me to resolve this issue as I am a returning Java programmer after a long time and I need your help guys, I shall be very thankful, also thanks in advance.

Here is my working code

```
public List<DigitalCertificate> listValidCertificates()
{
    final String methodName = "listValidCertificates";
    logger.entering(CLASS_NAME, methodName);

    try
    {
        QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner(getDataSource());
        ResultSetHandler<List<DigitalCertificate>> rsHandler = new BeanListHandler<DigitalCertificate>(DigitalCertificate.class);
        List<DigitalCertificate> certificates = run.query(SQL_VALID_CERTIFICATES, rsHandler);

        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER))
        {
            logger.logp(Level.FINER, CLASS_NAME, methodName, "run.query : executed.");
            logger.logp(Level.FINER, CLASS_NAME, methodName, "SQL Statement is " + SQL_VALID_CERTIFICATES);
        }

        logger.exiting(CLASS_NAME, methodName);
        return certificates;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

This is my failed Generic conversion

```
public List<?> runQuerySQLToGetList(String SQL, Object[] params)
{
    final String methodName = "runQuerySQLToGetList";
    Object methodParams [] = {SQL, params} ; 
    logger.entering(CLASS_NAME, methodName, params);

    try
    {
        QueryRunner run = new QueryRunner(getDataSource());
        ResultSetHandler<List<?>> rsHandler = new BeanListHandler<?>(?.class);

        List<?> certificates = run.query(SQL, rsHandler);

        if (logger.isLoggable(Level.FINER))
        {
            logger.logp(Level.FINER, CLASS_NAME, methodName, "run.query : executed.");
            logger.logp(Level.FINER, CLASS_NAME, methodName, "SQL Statement is " + SQL);
        }

        logger.exiting(CLASS_NAME, methodName);
        return certificates;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
}
```

Comment: That's invalid syntax. Please review your Generics tutorials, notes, etc.

Comment: Couple of things: 1. You'll have to use a named type not a wildcard (wildcards are placeholders for anything, anywhere; giving the type a name lets you explicitly specify where you want to use that type), and 2. You can't do `?.class`, or even `T.class`, you'll have either pass a `Class<T>` as a parameter to the method (for the same reason `BeanListHandle` takes a class as a constructor parameter) or you'll have to have an object of that type available for you to call `.getClass()` on. You may wish to read the [generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a generic type parameter instead of `?`:

```
public <T> List<T> runQuerySQLToGetList(String SQL, Object[] params, Class<T> clazz) {
...
    ResultSetHandler<List<T>> rsHandler = new BeanListHandler<T>(clazz);
...
}
```

Comment: That's a start. There will then be another set of issues with `List<?> certificates = run.query(SQL, rsHandler);`.